# SAS macro for mean change in baseline values

Tags: sas, summary, sas-macro

I have the following data:

```
Patient     Visit         VisitNumber    LAB        LABVALUE
001         BASELINE      1              LAB1       10
001         DAY 100       2              LAB1       15
001         DAY 200       3              LAB1       12
002         BASELINE      1              LAB1       11
002         DAY 100       2              LAB1       14
002         DAY 200       3              LAB1       12
001         BASELINE      1              LAB2       40
001         DAY 100       2              LAB2       45
001         DAY 200       3              LAB2       42
002         BASELINE      1              LAB2       41
002         DAY 100       2              LAB2       44
002         DAY 200       3              LAB2       42
```

I would like to create the following table, which summarizes the variable 'LABVALUE' for all patients at each visit (Table 2):

```
Visit       VisitNumber       LAB         MEAN            BASELINEMEAN        CHANGEBASEMEAN
BASELINE    1                 LAB1        10.5            10.5                .
DAY 100     2                 LAB1        14.5            10.5                4
DAY 200     3                 LAB1        12              10.5                1.5
BASELINE    1                 LAB2        40.5            40.5                .
DAY 100     2                 LAB2        44.5            40.5                4
DAY 200     3                 LAB2        42              40.5                1.5
```

I have the following code that generates the change in values from baseline for each visit by patient:

```
proc sort data=have;
  by patient lab visitnumber;
run;

data for_report;

  set have;
  by patient lab;

  retain base_visitnum base_labvalue;

  if first.patient then do;
    base_visitnum = .;
    base_labvalue = .;
  end;

  if first.lab and visit='BASELINE' then do;
    base_visitnumber = visitnumber;
    base_labvalue = labvalue;
  end;

  if not first.lab then do;
    delta_labvalue = labvalue - base_labvalue;
  end;

run;
```

This generates the following table:

```
   LAB      Visit     VisitNumber       LABVALUE        BASE_VISITNUM      BASE_LABVALUE   DELTA_LABVALUE
   LAB1     BASELINE  1                 10              1                  10              .
   LAB1     DAY 100   2                 15              1                  10              5
   LAB1     DAY 200   3                 12              1                  10              2 
   LAB1     BASELINE  1                 11              1                  11              .
   LAB1     DAY 100   2                 14              1                  11              3
   LAB1     DAY 200   3                 12              1                  11              1
   LAB2     BASELINE  1                 40              1                  10              .
   LAB2     DAY 100   2                 45              1                  10              5
   LAB2     DAY 200   3                 42              1                  10              2 
   LAB2     BASELINE  1                 41              1                  11              .
   LAB2     DAY 100   2                 44              1                  11              3
   LAB2     DAY 200   3                 42              1                  11              1
```

Any insight as to how I can generate Table 2 would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you most of the way there:

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table table2 as
    select visit,
           visitnumber,
           lab,
           mean(value) as mean,
           mean(base_labvalue) as baselinemean
    from for_report
    group by visit, visitnumber, lab
  ;
quit;
```

I've left some details for you to complete :-)

Also, watch out for the mismatch between `base_visitnum` and `base_visitnumber` in your example code.